# Loading Images asynchronous with ThreadPool

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to load an unknown amount of images into a ListView. Each image has its ViewModel with an Thumbnail property holding the image data. When the image is getting accessed and it's not loaded yet I want to return null, but at the same time start the loading process using the ThreadPool.

```
    public BitmapSource Thumbnail
        {
            get
            {
                if (_thumbnail == null)
                {
                    loadThumbnail(this);                    
                }

                return _thumbnail;
            }
            private set
            {
                _thumbnail = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Thumbnail));
            }
        }

        private static void loadThumbnail(ImageViewModel ivm)
        {            
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
            {
                BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
                bi.BeginInit();
                bi.DecodePixelWidth = 100;
                bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                bi.UriSource = new Uri(ivm.FilePath);
                bi.EndInit();
                bi.Freeze();
                ivm.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.DataBind, new setThumbnailCallback(ivm.setThumbnail),  bi );
            });
        }

        public delegate void setThumbnailCallback(BitmapSource image);

        private void setThumbnail(BitmapSource image)
        {
            Thumbnail = image;            
        }
```

XAML looks like this (called by a ListView):

```
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vmdl:ImageViewModel}">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image MaxWidth="100" MaxHeight="100"  Stretch="Uniform" Source="{Binding Path=Thumbnail}"/>
                <Label MaxWidth="100" Content="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
```

When I display the ListView the first few images get loaded just fine, but then it stops. After some time some more will appear, but there are holes in the list that are never loaded. I'm not talking here about the first 1000, but 15 of the first 20 get loaded, and a few seconds later images 40-45 while 20-39 remain blank. The rest never gets loaded. That said, the images that are not loaded are always the same, yet there is no noteworthy difference in size and location.

`Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(()=>` has the same behaviour. Changing `DispatcherPriority` also changes nothing.

If I were to load the images with a Thumbnail Converter, and the IsAsync tag it takes the program about a second to load all images without problem (so no performance problem). Yet I don't want to do this because it means the loaded image is within the view, and not the ViewModel, taking away control, wasting memory if I were to reuse it in another view, and having to reload it later again (not to mention the hundreds of threads this starts).

So my problem is that the images load not just slower, but also not at all at some parts. What am I missing?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: As a note, it seems odd that the loadThumbnail method is static, but takes a single ImageViewModel argument. Why not make it non-static, like `private void loadThumbnail()`? That said, does it make a difference if you replace `Invoke` with `BeginInvoke`?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to invoke the dispatcher to be able to set a property of a view model. What if you simply start a new `Task` that creates the `BitmapImage` and set the source property?

```
private static void loadThumbnail(ImageViewModel ivm)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
        bi.BeginInit();
        bi.DecodePixelWidth = 100;
        bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bi.UriSource = new Uri(ivm.FilePath);
        bi.EndInit();
        bi.Freeze();

        ivm.Thumbnail = bi;
    });
}
```

Comment: That would just spawn as many tasks are there are images, which is the purpose of the ThreadPool to prevent.

Comment: Yes, it will create as many *tasks* but the default task scheduler uses the thread pool to execute the tasks: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx. ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem is basically an older and somehow deprecated way of running some work on the thread pool. Since .NET 4 you use the TPL.